# Is there any similar method like secretsmanager:BatchGetSecretValue in AWS SDK v1.x?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-secrets-manager

I am using AWS SDK 1.12.97. I need to use `secretsmanager:BatchGetSecretValue` method in my project. But it seems that the method is not available in version 1.x. Is there any similar method in AWS SDK v1.x like `batchGetSecretValue()`? If not, is it possible to use the AWS SDK V2.x and AWS SDK V1.x in the same maven project at the same time?

Comment: Current version of the v1 Java SDK is 1.12.646, so it was probably added since your version. BTW, the v1 SDK is currently on an EOL plan, and won't be updated with new features after July of this year.